# extract data from specific column based on header in python

Tags: python, csv

I have a dataset (csv file) that contains water levels over time for many observation bores. For example

```
Time    REM_WELL1   REM_WELL2   DEEP_WELL_SYP   SP_1
1989.778        4.54        
1989.786                4.87
1989.806                
1990.531        4.46    4.5 4.7
1990.553                
1990.575                
1990.603    4.66    4.49    4.54    4.75
1990.908    4.71        4.61    4.6
1990.992    4.72    4.61    4.63    4.67
1991.106    4.41    4.59    4.58    4.82
1991.156    4.61    4.41    4.5 4.77
1991.256    4.61    4.37    4.49    4.75
```

I want to extract a column of data for a specific well (for example: SP100) by searching for its name on the first line and grab its water levels to plot a hydrograph. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: This is a good place to start http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module:

```
import csv

with open('well.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, dialect='excel-tab')
    rows = list(reader)

sp100 = [x.values() for x in rows if 'sp100' in x]
```

Or, if you need to do some more manipulation of data use the excellent [`pandas` library](http://pandas.pydata.org).

Comment: I tried your code but it didn't give me anything in sp100. What does "excel-tab" in your code mean?

Comment: Well it won't do anything, `'sp100'` is the name of your column header, so adjust that accordingly. For your other question, read the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)